# if statements and return var === somethingElse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, equivalent

I'm doing the Angular course on codeschool and passed one of the exercises by doing:

```
this.isSet = function(value) {
  if (value === this.tab) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

But in the next exercise, my code gets replaced by this:

```
this.isSet = function(tabName){
  return this.tab === tabName;
};
```

This must be a silly question, but can you bypass an if statement by just using a simple === ?

Comment: (x === y) is either true or false. The difference between the first and the second is that the second can also return false, if they are not equal

Comment: No, the two things don't mean the same thing. Just think about it -  a `return` always returns the expression, whereas a `return` wrapped in an if statement only returns when the if statement's body is executed. Otherwise, control flow would continue within the body of the function.

Comment: I know programmers, who write even: `if(bool_var == true) {return true;} else {return false;}` :)

Answer (score 1):

if value === this.tab, true will be returned, if value !== this.tab, undefined will be returned. In the second example === will return true and !== will return false. Undefined and false are both 'falsy', therefore you can use them in much the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you re-read your own code you'll see that the if statement does not add anything, and that if it fails, your function will return `undefined`, which is not optimal, as it's not a `boolean` value.

It's not a "bypass" (I don't quite understand what you mean by that), but the statement `return this.tab === tabName;` returns `true` or `false` depending on the evaluation result (which will always be a `boolean` value. I.e. the second code example returns the same value (`true`) as the first, when the values of `value`/`tabName` and `this.tab` respectively are equal (`===`).

Comment: What I meant to ask is if the two were interchangeable. I now understand that my statement could possibly return undefined rather than false.

Answer (score 0):

The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return false. It's this case where === will be faster, and may return a different result than ==. In all other cases performance will be the same.

See this tutorial for more details: http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm